# Proof of d'Alembert's ratio test: for sequences tending to infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

What would a proof for this theorem look like?

> Suppose that $(a_n)_n$ is a sequence such that $a_{n+1}/a_n$ tends to $\ell$. Prove that if $\ell>1$ and $a_n>0$ for all $n$ in the naturals, then $(a_n)_n$ tends to infinity.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: @user10354138 Right, I edited my comment after I saw your edit.

Comment: Well, $a_{n+k}>\ell^ka_n$

Answer (score 0):

If
$\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
\to L$
then,
for any $c > 0$
there is a $n(c)$
such that
$\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
\gt L-c$
for
$n > n(c)$.

Since
$L > 1$,
let $d = L-1 > 0$.
We can choose $c < d/2$.

Then,
for $n > n(c)$,
$\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
\gt L-c
\gt L-(L-1)/2
=(1+L)/2
=(1+1+d)/2
=1+d/2
$
so 
$\dfrac{a_{n+k}}{a_n}
\gt (1+d/2)^k
\to \infty
$
as
$k \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $l>1$, there exists $N$ such that, for $n\ge N$,
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}>k>1
$$
(take, for instance, $k=(l+1)/2$). Therefore, assuming $a_N>0$,
$$
a_{N+1}>ka_{N},\quad
a_{N+2}>ka_{N+1}>k^2a_{N},\quad\dots
$$
and, by induction,
$$
a_{N+p}>k^pa_N
$$
for every $p$.

If $a_N<0$, then
$$
a_{N+p}<k^pa_N
$$