# Converge/Diverge $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{3^{n^2}}{(n!)^3}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{3^{n^2}}{(n!)^3}$$

We first absolutely convergence:

$$\big|(-1)^n\frac{3^{n^2}}{(n!)^3}\big|\leq \frac{3^{n^2}}{(n!)^3}$$

We first check $a_n\to 0$

Can we say that if $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}>1$$

We can conclude that $a_n\not \to 0$?

Comment: @Masacroso $$a_n = n^{-2}$$ implies $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2},$$ not $(n+1)^2/n^2$ as you have written.

Comment: @heropup yes, my bad, I was reading the ratio wrongly

Comment: Yes. There's also a related theorem involving limits. Take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2971407/proof-of-dalemberts-ratio-test-for-sequences-tending-to-infinity or at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2516157/why-does-the-ratio-test-prove-that-this-particular-sequence-converges-on-0

Answer (score 3):

If you define $$a_n = (-1)^n \frac{3^{n^2}}{(n!)^3},$$ then $$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| = \left|\frac{3^{2n+1}}{(n+1)^3}\right|.$$  Then by the ratio test, the series is not absolutely convergent as this exceeds $1$.

Comment: So the series is not absolutely convergent, but how can I conclude that it is divergent?

Comment: @newhere Find an expression for the partial sum or a bound on the magnitude of the partial sum.

Answer (score 3):

We have since $n!<n^n$, $$\frac{3^{n^2}}{(n!)^3}>\exp(n^2\ln(3)-3 n \ln(n))\to\infty$$ so the terms don't converge to $0$ and hence the series is divergent by the [term test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because then$$(\forall n\in\mathbb N):a_n>a_1^{\,n}$$and $a_1>1$.